# ffmpeg brew yasm

Tags: ffmpeg, homebrew, yasm

I'm trying to install ffmpeg via brew. It error I get with yasm is

"Error: You must `brew link pkg-config yasm' before ffmpeg can be installed"

When doing so I'm told that my permissions are insufficient.

"Linking /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.28... Warning: Could not link pkg-config.   Unlinking...
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/share/doc"

The permissions are -rw-rw--- . I've tried unlinking yasm package and then redoing it with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

1. Go to whatever directory they specify in the terminal
2. and then do `chown <your username> .` or for a subfolder `chown <your username> someFolder`
3. sometimes that does not work for all directories, so use `sudo chown <your username> .` and enter your password
4. now try to relink yasm, `brew link yasm` and then once that is done `brew install ffmpeg` should work

Answer (score 1):

My `/usr/local/share/doc` is

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

owned by my user name and group `admin`.  Try that.

Also try `brew doctor`.